# How to index a composite primary key with non-sequential inserts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index, clustered-index

I have a composite primary key, comprising of a datetime, a location id and a 2 character code. This is the key that uniquely identifies each row of my table.

I know that the usage of this table will insert a week of data from a year ago, then a week of data from this year. Therefore, it's likely the table will get fragmented, as the primary key jumps back and forth.

I would like to know what sort of indexing strategies can be employed in this scenario. My gut feeling is that the default clustered index is a bad idea and I should replace that with a non-clustered index, which would make rebuilds easier.

Comment: I would have a surrogate key on an identity field and a unique nonclustered index on the composite key columns you mentioned. Also, don't worry about index fragmentation so much.

Comment: I wouldn't expect fragmentation to be an issue if source data are ordered, including a sort operator in a `INSERT...SELECT` from a weekly data staging table. The fragmentation caused by the initial split for each weekly insert should affect query performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about fragmentation, do you have a maintenance solution on your server that addresses that such as [SQL Server Maintenance Solution - Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/)?

---

Questions:

- datetime data type is date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2(0-2),datetime2(3-4), datetime(5+) or?
- LocationId data type is tinyint, smallint, int, bigint or ?
- Character code data type is char(2), nchar(2) or?

---

More Questions:

- How many rows are in your table?
- Would you need an int or bigint for a surrogate id?
- What are the other columns in your table?
- Are all queries filtered by datetime, or are filtered by the locationid and/or character code?
- Are you always returning the whole row, or sometimes just pieces of it?

---

Because most people assume the Primary Key is the Clustering Key, I am going to interpret your question as "How to index a composite clustering key with non-sequential inserts?".

The situation you are considering is related to debates like [The Clustered Index Debate](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/) and [Surrogate Key vs. Natural Key](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3922066/SQL-Server-Natural-Key-Verses-Surrogate-Key.htm).

In this situation, I would want to consider the impact of a [16?] byte composite clustering key vs a 4 or 8 byte clustering key (int / bigint). My decision tree would look something like this:

1. Will we be using Hekaton (In-Memory OLTP)?

   - Yes => composite key. [**Run away**.](http://dbareactions.com/tagged/hekaton)
   - No => Good call, continue...
2. How many rows will this table have?

   - Tens of millions, maybe more! => surrogate key (probably).

     - If the data length of each row will be variable and not narrow => surrogate key.
     - If the data length of the row will be fixed and narrow, and it results in optimal page usage => continue...
   - Less than that => continue...
3. How will the table be queried?

   - Various combinations of and not always all of `datetime, location_id, character_code` => surrogate key.

     - In this case you may want to be able to have multiple supporting indexes the combinations of `datetime, location_id, character_code` for your queries.
       The clustering key is included in all non-clustered indexes, and the larger it is the more space/pages each index entry will require. => surrogate key.
   - Almost always by all three `datetime, location_id, character_code` or almost always by `datetime` or `datetime, location_id`; 
     but not by `location_id` without `datetime` and not `character_code` without `datetime, location_id` (zero or only a couple of non-clustered indexes on this table) => continue...
4. Will any other table reference this table?

   - Yes => surrogate key.
   - No => composite key is a reasonable option

---

Even if my first run through of the above decision tree leads me to a composite key, I would probably start my design using a surrogate key because it is easier to get rid of it (because it isn't being used) than to go back and add it and implement its use.

Just to clarify, I have had cases where I did find that the composite key was a better solution and did refactor the design to drop the surrogate key. I don't want to leave the impression that the surrogate key is always the better solution, even if it is a common default for many designers (including myself).

---

Reference:

- [A Simple Start – Table Creation Best Practices - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/a-simple-start-table-creation-best-practices/) - concerning row size and page utilization
- [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues… - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [More considerations for the clustering key – the clustered index debate continues! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [How much does that key cost? (plus sp_helpindex9) - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/how-much-does-that-key-cost-plus-sp_helpindex9/)
- [101 Things I Wish You Knew About Sql Server - Thomas LaRock](http://thomaslarock.com/2015/06/101-things-i-wish-you-knew-about-sql-server/)
- [SQL Server: Natural Key Verses Surrogate Key - Database Journal - Gregory A. Larsen](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3922066/SQL-Server-Natural-Key-Verses-Surrogate-Key.htm)
- [Ten Common Database Design Mistakes - Simple Talk - Louis Davidson](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/)
- [Hekaton (In-Memory OLTP) - dbareactions.com](http://dbareactions.com/tagged/hekaton)

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive on if this would reduce page splits but I would put date last if that has the most changes.

Have a fill factor of less than 100%.  Even 90% or 80% will slow down fragmentation significantly.

Have a maintenance plan to reorganize / rebuild the index.

A non-clustered index will use more room but it would make for more efficient maintenance.  You can place a unique constraint on a non-clustered index.